# Trying to get property of non-object while using kartik-v for image uploading in Yii2

Tags: yii2, image-uploading

I'm using [yii2-widget-fileinput](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput) for an image uploading in a form. 
When I click on upload or the create button I get `Trying to get property of non-object` error in controller.

**Controller**

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        Yii::$app->params['uploadPath'] = Yii::$app->basePath . '/uploads/';
        $model = new Ads();
        $provinces = ArrayHelper::map(Province::find()->all(), 'name', 'name'); 
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){

            $image = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'image');
            $model->filename = $image->name;
            $ext = end((explode(".", $image->name)));
            $avatar = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString().".{$ext}";
            $path = Yii::$app->params['uploadPath'].$avatar;
            if ($model->save()) {

                $image->saveAs($path);
                $model->image_adr = $path;
                return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
            }else{
                echo "error on saving the model";
            }

        }
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
            'provinces'=>$provinces,
            ]);
    }
```

**model rules**

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['type', 'explanation', 'cost', 'province_name', 'address'], 'required'],
            [['type', 'explanation', 'image_adr', 'address'], 'string'],
            [['cost'], 'integer'],
            [['province_name'], 'string', 'max' => 20],
            [['province_name'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Province::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['province_name' => 'name']],
            [['image'],'safe'],
            [['image'], 'file', 'extensions'=>'jpg, gif, png', 'maxFiles'=>3,],
        ];
```

and finnally the **view**

```
    <?= $form->field($model, 'image[]')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
    'options'=>['accept'=>'image/*', 'multiple'=>true],
    'pluginOptions'=>['allowedFileExtensions'=>['jpg','gif','png'], 'overwriteInitial'=>false,]
            ]); ?>
```

the problem should refer to this part in the controller I think

```
$image = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'image');
```

An image of the error might be helpful

[image: property of non-object error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when you're using `UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'image');`  you should work with `foreach` or treat it like an array.

Something that made me a problem was that even if you're using `UploadedFile::getInstanc` *(notice the obsoleted s in the end)* you should still treat it like an array and in all parts you should use `$image[0]`, not `$iamge` lonely.

Answer (score 1):

You should check first is image in post or not.

```
....

$image = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'image'); //getInstanceByName

if (!empty($image))
   $model->filename = $image->name;

  .....
  if ($model->save()) {
        if (!empty($image))
                $image->saveAs($path);
.........
```

Make sure in your form ency type is added:

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([ 
'id' => 'form_id', 
'options' => [ 
'class' => 'form_class', 
'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data', 
], 
]);
```

Comment: yeah as the error says, the `$image = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'image');` isn't returning what you want, and yeah the image is not in post. what should I do?

Comment: are you sure , encytype multipart data is added in your form?

Comment: still same problem, I've updated the question with an image.